# Convert Text Annotation to Layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, annotation

Is there a way to convert annotation into a layer?

[It has been asked ten years ago](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64504/can-one-convert-text-annotations-to-a-layer-in-qgis) but is there now a more straightforward solution?

I have many text annotations that I need to convert to a point layer.

I tried to use the tool to transfer annotations to an annotation layer, but it doesn't seem to work, and it's a special layer that cannot be exported, or fused with other layers.

Comment: lease check out this plug in, let me know if it works for you: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ConvertLabels/

Comment: Thank you, but this plugin is for labels and not annotation. For that, there is also the extract label tool in QGIS.